# limits.conf: noproc or nproc?

Tags: linux, centos-5

I'm using centos 5.x, and editing /etc/security/limits.conf now.

I found in the comments, it's:

```
- nofile - max number of open files
- nproc - max number of processes
```

One is `nofile`, another is `nproc`. And when I search internet, I found some examples are using `noproc`.

So, which is correct? Or both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comments tell you the story:  **Number** of **Open FILEs** vs. **Number** of **PROCesses**.  See also [the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/limits.conf), which shows **nproc** and **nofile** and nowhere is *noproc* to be seen.

Comment: Hooray man pages!